# Is there any keyword to serve as "Wait until Keywords Succeed"?

Tags: robotframework

Is there any keyword that could do the same as "Wait Until Keywords Succeed" in Robot Framework or would I have to create a new keyword altogether? I am fairly new to the framework and I wish to achieve the following:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10x    20s
...    ${response} =    Some Keyword    arg
...    Should Match    ${response}    ${val}
```

Or is there another way to work around this?

Comment: Are you asking how to run more than one keyword with `wait until keyword succeeds`?

Comment: Yes. Is that is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by excluding those keywords into a composite keyword:

```
My Keyword
[Arguments]    ${argument}    ${val}
    ${response} =    Some Keyword    ${argument}
    Should Match    ${response}    ${val}
```

And then calling this keyword under "Wait Until Keyword Succeeds" with correct attributes

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    My Keyword    ${argument}    ${val}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're wanting to run multiple keywords, there are two solutions. One is to put those multiple keywords inside another keyword, and then call that. There's already [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505705/7432) to show how to do that.

The other solution is to run [run keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords). For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    wait until keyword succeeds  30 seconds  10 seconds  run keywords
    ...  log  this is one keyword
    ...  AND  log  this could be a different keyword
    ...  AND  log  and this could be another keyword
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The first method you suggested worked for this particular situation, and your second solution helped me in the following:
    Run Keyword If Any Tests Failed
    ...    Run Keywords
    ...    Keyword1
    ...    AND    Keyword2

Comment: In the second solution you suggested for this particular problem, I was not able to set 
${response} =    Some Keyword    arg
and access it with the Should Match keyword in the next line. It was throwing the "${response} variable not found" error.